# ACL permissions mysteriously giving execute on group

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, acl

I did the following and I don't understand the end result:

```
$ mkdir mydir
$ setfacl -d -m u::rwX,g::rwX,o::rX,m::rwx mydir
$ touch mydir/test.txt
$ getfacl mydir/test.txt
# file: mydir/test.txt
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rw-
group::rwx          #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--

$ setfacl -m g::rwX mydir/test.txt
$ getfacl mydir/test.txt
# file: mydir/test.txt
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rw-
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

So, here's what I expect to be happening:

1. make directory and set defaults for newly created files within that directory (the 'X' is executable if a directory or only executable for a regular file if already executable)
2. `touch` makes a new file with 'rw-rw-r--' permissions and a 'rwx' mask
3. `setfacl -m g::rwX mydir/test.txt` should do nothing as the file should already have group 'rw-' with a mask of 'rwx'

What is actually happening is:

1. directory is created by the reported defaults are:

```
    default:user::rwx
    default:group::rwx
    default:mask::rwx
    default:other::r-x
```

2. `touch` makes a file that shows 'rw-rw-r--' in `ls` but `getfacl` shows that the group permission is actually 'rwx' and is just masked to be 'rw-' because the mask is 'rw-' instead of the default 'rwx'
3. since test.txt is already group 'rwx' then `setfacl -m g::rwX mydir/test.txt` doesn't change the group permission, but does cause the mask to be recalculated to 'rwx' which makes the 'x' permission on the group show through in `ls` now.

**Why is the default mask on the directory not applied to the new file?  Why does the new file's group permission include an execute bit?**

Here's the `getfacl` on the mydir:

```
# file: mydir
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

**Why does `getfacl` not include 'X' (capitalized) and only show 'x' in the default settings?**

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this? I'm seeing a similar issue and posted it here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1113951/giving-execute-permission-on-folder-with-acl-makes-files-executable-too

Comment: @bobsoap - Sorry, I don't even remember having the problem and haven't used these ACL tools since so have forgotten everything.